# Weak Lower Semicontinuity Generalized to any $L_{p}$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

I am having difficulty with the following proof:

Generalize the weak lower semi-continuity of$L^{p}$ norms to all $1\leq p < \infty$; i.e., show that if $u_{n}\to u$ weakly in $L^{p}$, then

$||u||_{L^{p}}\leq \inf_{k}||u_{k}||_{L^{p}}$.

We were given the following hint: Consider the integral $\int uv$, with $v=|u|^{p-2}\bar{u}$ (where $\bar{u}$ is the complex conjugate of $u$), and note that $v \in L^{q}$, where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. (One of the things I'm not seeing, actually, is how $v \in L^{q}$, so if somebody could explain that to me, first of all, that would be great!)

Now, in class, we showed the case for $L^{2}$, so I've been trying to use that to help me generalize. This is how that case went: $||u||^{2}=|\int u \bar{u}|=\lim_{k}|\int u \bar{u}_{k}|\leq \lim \inf ||u|| ||u_{k}||=||u|| \lim \inf ||u_{k}||$, and then dividing both sides by $||u||$, we obtain $||u||\leq \lim inf ||u_{k}||$.

Using the hint, this is what I've done so far on the problem:

$||u||_{L^{p}}^{p}=\left(\int|u|^{p}\right) = \left( |u|^{2+p-2}\right)=\left(\int|u|^{2}|u|^{p-2}\right)=\left(\int uv\right) = \lim_{k}$ something. I don't know if I'm supposed to take a conjugate like we did in the example from class, or if somehow the fact that $v \in L^{q}$ is supposed to come into play at this point...

I am very confused about what to do at this point, or whether what I did so far is even correct. If you could help me out with this (and not be snarky if it turns out I am asking something completely inane), I would be so thankful!

I should point out that whole this IS a homework problem, we are NOT being graded on it. I am genuinely lost and just want to learn and understand how to approach proofs like this from now on.

Answer (score 2):

The function $v$ belongs to $\mathbb L^q$ because $|v|=|u|^{p-1}$, $q=\frac p{p-1}$ and $u\in\mathbb L^p$.

Then the idea is similar of the case $p=2$: we use the definition of weak convergence with the given $v$ and Hölder's inequality instead of Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: If I do that, this is what happens: $||u||_{L^{p}}=\left(\int|u|^{p}\right)^{1/p}=\left(\int|u|^{2+p-2}\right)^{1/p}=\left(\int|u|^{2}|u|^{p-2}\right)^{1/p}\leq \left( \int u \bar{u}|u|^{p-2}\right)^{1/p}\leq \left( |\int u \bar{u}|u|^{p-2}|\right)^{1/p}\leq \left(\int| u | |\bar{u}|u|^{p-2}|\right)^{1/p}\leq \left( \int |u||v|\right)^{1/p}\leq\left(\int |u|\right)^{1/p}\left(\int |v|\right)^{1/p}$ (by Holder's).  Now, the problem is, I don't have any more $L^{p}$ norms on the RHS, and I've got a $v$ that I don't know what to do with!

Comment: After your first $\leqslant$ (which should be an equality), use the definition of weak convergence.

Comment: Back to the showing that $v\in L^{q}$, I want to fill in the steps. I think they are: $|v|=| |u|^{p-2}\bar{u} | = |u|^{p-2} |\bar{u}| = |u|^{p-2}|u|=|u|^{p-1}=|u|^{p/q}$. Then, it would seem to imply that $|v|^{q}=|u|^{p}$. Now, is it because this is true, given that $u \in L^{p}$, that $v \in L^{q}$? I'm sorry for my incessant, probably inane sounding follow-up comments, but my measure theory background is not great, and it is important that I learn this material.

Comment: Indeed, we have $|v|=|u|^{p/q}$ hence $|v|^q=|u|^p$ and $|v|^q$ is equal to an integrable function.